# Jquery wildcard selectors for calling plugin?

Tags: jquery, wildcard, jquery-cycle

To keep it brief, I'm trying to select #small-cycle1, #small-cycle2, etc. for the jquery cycle plugin.  Using wild cards to select it does not seem to be working, as it writes out the pager nav of ALL cycles into each cycle.

Below is how I'm getting around the problem for now.

```
        $('#small-cycle1').cycle({ 
            speed:       0, 
            timeout:     0,
            pager:      '#nav1',
            pagerEvent: 'mouseover', 
            pauseOnPagerHover: true
        });
        $('#small-cycle2').cycle({ 
            speed:       0, 
            timeout:     0,
            pager:      '#nav2',
            pagerEvent: 'mouseover', 
            pauseOnPagerHover: true
        });
        $('#small-cycle3').cycle({ 
            speed:       0, 
            timeout:     0,
            pager:      '#nav3',
            pagerEvent: 'mouseover', 
            pauseOnPagerHover: true
        });
        $('#small-cycle4').cycle({ 
            speed:       0, 
            timeout:     0,
            pager:      '#nav4',
            pagerEvent: 'mouseover', 
            pauseOnPagerHover: true
        });
        $('#small-cycle5').cycle({ 
            speed:       0, 
            timeout:     0,
            pager:      '#nav5',
            pagerEvent: 'mouseover', 
            pauseOnPagerHover: true
        });
```

Is it possible to use wildcards in the selector and for the pager: option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the cycle plugin but this code should select all the elements you want. Just set 'cycleCount' to the number of slideshows you have on the page and it will loop through them.

```
var cycleCount = 5;
for(var i = 1; i <= cycleCount;i++){
    $('#small-cycle'+i).cycle({ 
        speed:       0, 
        timeout:     0,
        pager:      '#nav'+i,
        pagerEvent: 'mouseover', 
        pauseOnPagerHover: true
    });
}
```

Comment: This works.  I'm wondering if i can just put var cycleCount = 999; or if that will slow the page down?

It shouldn't ever really be more than 5... but if I need to limit it to whatever is actually needed, I might just have our programmer track the number needed and feed it into cycleCount.

Comment: If you put the count higher than the available number of divs then it will slow it down a bit. You could add a class to each `#small-cycle` e.g. `.cycle-wrap` then set cycleCount to `$(".cycle-wrap").length`. That way you'd never have to manually update the number.

Comment: Actually, I already have a class like that on each one.  Thanks for the idea.

Comment: var cycleCount = $('.small-cycle').length;  Works